# Placing the institution logo at the top

Tags: beamer

I need to put the logo of the institution at the top before the title and centralized. How do I do that? When I add:

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{ifce.png}}
```

appears soon after the date. But I need to put the right before all centralized.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is an English speaking site. Don't worry, some of our Brazilian fellows will translate.

Comment: You could redefine the definition of the title page. Can you please tell us, which theme you are using?

Comment: Oi Larissa, seja bem-vinda a nossa comunidade TeX! Este é um website internacional e a troca de mensagens é feita exclusivamente em inglês. Não se preocupe, um de nossos amigos tomou a liberdade de traduzir sua postagem. `:)`

Comment: Larissa, you are using the right macro, but the image placement is heavily dependant on the used theme. We might need more info on your code, so we can provide the correct adjustments.